# Count number of records with sum of multiple columns equal to 0 in mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with  stocks of different warehouse columns are there.
I need to find out the records matching the below criteria.Its a mysql database.

Count number of records with sum of multiple columns equal to 0.

Structure of table

```
Stock A | Stock B | Stock C | Stock D
0       | 1       | 0       | 0
0       | 0       | 0       | 0
1       | 1       | 1        | 1
```

Here the output will be 1.

Comment: Google: Accessing databases with PHP and SQL.

Comment: SELECT (Stock A + Stock B + Stock C +  Stock D) AS SUM FROM  warehouse GROUP BY id. This query returns all  rows with sum  = 0.And after that  need to run a loop to get the count of rows with zero sum.So if possible to do with mysql query that will be faster

Comment: `select count(*) ... where a+b+c+d = 0`

Comment: OP: please don't put code in comments... edit your answer and add it there so it can be more easily seen by all and properly formatted. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you have a table with stocks of different warehouse columns?

Comment: Don't use `GROUP BY` when you don't know what it does. This goes especially for MySQL, as it is less strict about its usage than other DBMS.

Comment: @anupkumar If one of the answers below helped you, can you please mark them as accepted to close out your question?

Answer (score 0):

This should be fairly simple:

```
create table test (stock_a int, stock_b int, stock_c int, stock_d int);
insert into test values (0,1,0,0), (0,0,0,0), (1,1,1,1);

select count(*) from test where stock_a + stock_b + stock_c + stock_d = 0

Result:
count(*)
--------
1
```

Answer (score 0):

Sum of multiple columns are in the where clause so the Count(1) only counts where summ of all fields is zero.

```
Select Count(1) From warehouse 
Where (`Stock A` + `Stock B` + `Stock C` + `Stock D`) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you won't have negative values in yourtable, then you can just do this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) As cnt
FROM yourtable
WHERE (Stock_A, Stock_B, Stock_C, Stock_D) = (0, 0, 0, 0)
```